# How do I install PHPUnit 3.5, instead of 3.6?

Tags: phpunit, pear

The current version of PHPUnit is 3.6, but until I update my code I need to use 3.5.15 instead. I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get 3.5.15 installed.

I start with a clean install of Zend Server, which only has a few basic PEAR packages installed. I channel-discover pear.phpunit.de and pear.symfony-project.com. Then I try installing 3.5.15 from a URL, but it fails:

```
# pear install http://pear.phpunit.de/get/PHPUnit-3.5.15.tgz
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.15.tgz ...
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.5.15 found
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.0 found
install failed
```

Next, I try installing from a downloaded file, but that also fails:

```
# pear install ~/Desktop/PHPUnit-3.5.15.tgz 
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.5.15 found
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.0 found
install failed
```

And then from PEAR directly ... which installs 3.6 instead of what I asked for!

```
# pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear/XML_RPC2"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/DbUnit requires package "phpunit/PHPUnit" (version >= 3.6.0), downloaded version is 3.5.15
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "phpunit/DbUnit" (version >= 1.0.0)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.0.0)
downloading File_Iterator-1.3.0.tgz ...
downloading Text_Template-1.1.1.tgz ...
downloading PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.0.tgz ...
downloading PHP_Timer-1.0.2.tgz ...
downloading PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.0.tgz ...
downloading PHPUnit_Selenium-1.1.0.tgz ...
downloading YAML-1.0.6.tgz ...
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.0.tgz ...
downloading PHP_TokenStream-1.1.0.tgz ...
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.0
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/Text_Template-1.1.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer-1.0.2
install ok: channel://pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.6
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_TokenStream-1.1.0
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.0
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.0
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.0
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.1.0
```

Even using the -f option, to try to force an installation of the version I asked for, doesn't change anything.

How do I get 3.5.15 installed?

Comment: I figured it out, partly. PHPUnit-3.5.15 requires DbUnit, but the latest version of DbUnit (1.1.0) requires PHPUnit-3.6. So that's why, when I installed PHPUnit 3.5.15, 3.6 would be installed instead. I worked around the problem by specifically installing DbUnit-1.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit-3.5.15 requires DbUnit, but the latest version of DbUnit (1.1.0) requires PHPUnit-3.6. So that's why, when I installed PHPUnit 3.5.15, 3.6 would be installed instead. I worked around the problem by specifically installing DbUnit-1.0.3.

I'll accept my own answer, but it's not a complete answer - an attempt to install PHPUnit 3.5 results in the installation of a module which then forces the install of PHPUnit 3.6, and that doesn't seem right. This looks like a packaging problem, but I couldn't figure out where to report it.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of dependencies you have to deal with to have Pear NOT forcibly install PHPUnit 3.6. Here's what I did to get PHPUnit 3.5.15 installed: http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

Answer (score 3):

I have not been able to install PHPUnit correctly on Ubuntu

Am installing on widnows 7 now 
following advice from here
http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

and abstracting it :) now hopeful that I will be able to install upon
ubuntu too

--

It worked now have phpunit correct version installed.

Answer (score 1):

To get the question from the unanswered list:

---

PHPUnit-3.5.15 requires DbUnit, but the latest version of DbUnit (1.1.0) requires PHPUnit-3.6.

So that's why, when I installed PHPUnit 3.5.15, 3.6 would be installed instead. I worked around the problem by specifically installing DbUnit-1.0.3

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me
http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/

Answer (score 0):

install it via composer:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "pear.symfony-project.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "pear.phpunit.de"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/phpunit": "3.5.15",
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage": "1.0.*",
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator": "1.2.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: At the time I originally asked this question, Composer had not yet been released.